# Regex to match one portion of a string

Tags: php, regex

I have this types of strings:

`aabbcc-12-00001-g001-1024.png`

`ddeeffgg-1-50001-i001-500.jpg`

`ddeeffgg-1-50001-i001.jpg`

I would like to extract the filename without it's size, which is always the `-xxx` or `-xxxx` before the file extension.

For example, for the three strings, I would like to match:

`aabbcc-12-00001-g001.png`

`ddeeffgg-1-50001-i001.jpg`

`ddeeffgg-1-50001-i001.jpg`

My idea was to first march the size, then use preg_replace with PHP, but not sure how to only match the size, trying with:

```
-\d{3,4}\.[a-z]{3}
```

But this is matching -550.png or -1024.jpg etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use preg_replace with a substitution:

```
$str = 'aabbcc-12-00001-g001-1024.png';
$result = preg_replace('/(-\d+)(.[A-Z]+)$/i', '$2', $str);
echo $result;
```